# Which part of differential geomety uses metrization theorems?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I learned three metrization theorems last year, which are Nagata-Smirnov,Smirnov and Bing.

I thought these theorems are purely topological theorems, but i recently saw a post which says these theorems are used in differential geometry, then i got surprised. (However, i hardly trust this since i found this post in physics forum..)

Which parts of differential geometry use metrization theorems? I have no idea which parts are those and i think even if this subject uses metrization theorems, Urysohn's metrization theorem would be more than sufficient which is strictly weaker than those "*if and only if*metrization theorems".